# Reliable way to scroll to bottom of UITableView with footerview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

This is driving me insane...I know there are many similar questions but none seem to work consistently. I have a UITableView that conditionally has a footerView set, and I have a method to scroll to the bottom of the view

```
- (void)scrollToBottom {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if (self.tableView.tableFooterView && self.tableView.tableFooterView.frame.size.height > 0) {
        [self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:self.tableView.tableFooterView.frame animated:YES];
    } else {
        if ([self.tableView numberOfSections] > 0) {
            NSInteger numRows = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0];
            if (numRows > 0){
                NSIndexPath* ipath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: numRows - 1 inSection: 0];
                [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath: ipath atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated: YES];
            }
        }
    }
});
}
```

which gets called in my `controllerDidChangeContent` method after `[self.tableView endUpdates];` (though I've tried calling the same method in many different spots). The `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` works like a charm every time, but the `scrollRectToVisible` only works occasionally. When I put a breakpoint in I can see that the `tableView.contentSize.height` is only 60.0 (the height of the footerView). Is there somewhere else I can call this method where I know the content would be fully loaded? Can I just piggyback on the `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` version and bump the contentOffset or something? Any new ideas would be greatly appreciated (my keyboard and face will thank you for preventing me from bashing them together any further).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I have a fix, though I don't know why it's necessary. I just had to add `[self.tableView reloadData]` before the code within my scroll method, making it:

```
- (void)scrollToBottom {
[self.tableView reloadData];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if (self.tableView.tableFooterView && self.tableView.tableFooterView.frame.size.height > 0) {
        [self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:self.tableView.tableFooterView.frame animated:YES];
    } else {
        if ([self.tableView numberOfSections] > 0) {
            NSInteger numRows = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0];
            if (numRows > 0){
                NSIndexPath* ipath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: numRows - 1 inSection: 0];
                [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath: ipath atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated: YES];
            }
        }
    }
});
}
```

Strangely, the same `reloadData` is being called a few times immediately before this call so I'm not sure why this works, but maybe someone else has a good explanation (at least better than my "I tried it and it worked" one).

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing layout first:

```
if (self.tableView.tableFooterView && self.tableView.tableFooterView.frame.size.height > 0) {
    [self.tableView layoutIfNeeded];
    [self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:self.tableView.tableFooterView.frame animated:YES];

} else ...
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have any effect unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Instead of scrollToRowAtIndex Path, use:

```
CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0,self.tableView.contentSize.height);
[self.tableView setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES];
```

Comment: This would be a good replacement for the scrollToRowAtIndex, but the main problem I'm facing is that self.tableView.contentSize.height is only 60.0 (the height of the footerView) when that method gets called.